# PHP replacing multiple lines in a file

Tags: php, variables, line, fopen, fwrite

I am able to choose a single line of a file(eg. **dummy.php**) and replace it with a text stored in a variable, called `$currentdate` but I want to choose several lines and replace them with several variables. For example:

`$site_name` in 2nd line,

`$URL` in 4th line,

`$protocol` in line 6,

`$author` in line 8,

`$description` in line 10

And
`$currentdate` in line 12.

I've made this code, which replaces second line:

```
        $currentdate = date('d F Y');
$filename = getcwd() . "/dummy.php"; 
$date_line = 1; 
$lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES ); 
$lines[$date_line] =    "$currentdate";
file_put_contents( $filename , implode( "\n", $lines ) );
```

I repeat the question, how to add several variables in several lines of that fine?
Example variables and line numbers are given in this question.
Also, I've made a code, but I don't know, whether it will work or not. I can't try adding this code to my project files, because I'm scared of being my code worse and disabling other codes, which are also stood in that page.
Here is the non-tested code:

```
$site_name_line = 1; 
$URL_line = 3; 
$protocol_line = 5; 
$author_line = 7; 
$description_line = 9; 
$currentdate_line = 11;
$lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES ); 
$lines[$site_name_line] =   "$site_name";
$lines[$URL_line] = "$URL";
$lines[$protocol_line] =    "$protocol";
$lines[$author_line] =  "$author";$lines[$description_line] =   "$description";$lines[$currentdate_line] =  "$currentdate";
file_put_contents( $filename , implode( "\n", $lines ) );
```

Comment: So what is the question you want to ask?

Comment: @matiit how to add multiple variables in multiple lines?

Comment: It will look very similar but it will be more flexible. Try thinking about it as: You need to write a function that takes, say, one associative array with line numbers as keys and replacements as values - then you'll need to repeat your code in a loop iterating over that argument.

Comment: Adding needed code to the answer, will be more helpful. For PHP masters, it won't be any harder.

Comment: spoon feeding is banned on SO

Comment: @user8783930 that is called doing your work for you

Comment: @user8683930 I am coming from different angle I think. 
SO should not be a free.... and someone said it in one sentence, thank you Tarun

Comment: Hey, I didn't mean that. I'm a little weak on server side scripting. I was just saying, that adding related code will be more helpful. If you know the answer, and doesn't want to tell me about the codings, then please, atleast tell me the idea to do the thing!

Comment: I think I gave you the idea above

Comment: Can you explain arrays and loops? I don't know much about those two things

Comment: Will this work?:$site_name_line = 1; 
$URL_line = 3; 
$protocol_line = 5; 
$author_line = 7; 
$description_line = 9; 
$currentdate_line = 11;
$lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES ); 
$lines[$site_name_line] = "$site_name";
$lines[$URL_line] = "$URL";
$lines[$protocol_line] = "$protocol";
$lines[$author_line] = "$author";$lines[$description_line] = "$description";$lines[$currentdate_line] = "$currentdate";
file_put_contents( $filename , implode( "\n", $lines ) ); I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Will it work huh?

Comment: You can edit your message adding this code and then we can see, 
also, please be more patient, we are trying to help here totally non-profit, slight appreciation wouldn't hurt

Comment: Well, that's great. Thanks a lot! Helping others without thinking of any profit, is great and needs a lot appreciates. I'm saying a 10000000000 thanks!

Comment: Thank you for editing your question, I will try to help.

Comment: @matiit you don't have to thank. I asked you to help me on solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer myself. I didn't thought, I could. But I did it. Here is the whole PHP code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['post'])){

// GET EMAIL
        $site_name = $_POST["site_name"];
        $URL = $_POST["URL"];
        $protocol = $_POST["protocol"];
        $author = $_POST["author"];
         $description = $_POST["description"];
        $currentdate = date('d F Y');
$filename = getcwd() . "/dummy.php"; 
$site_name_line = 1; 
$URL_line = 3; 
$protocol_line = 5; 
$author_line = 7; 
$description_line = 9; 
$currentdate_line = 11;
$lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES ); 
$lines[$site_name_line] =   "$site_name";
$lines[$URL_line] = "$URL";
$lines[$protocol_line] =    "$protocol";
$lines[$author_line] =  "$author";$lines[$description_line] =   "$description";$lines[$currentdate_line] =  "$currentdate";
file_put_contents( $filename , implode( "\n", $lines ) );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Replace lines with given content.
  *
  * $substitutions array should look
  * [
  *   1 => "new first line content",
  *   4 => "new fourth line content",
  * ]
  *
  * @param string $filename
  * @param array $substitutions
  */
  function replaceLines($filename, array $substitutions) {
     $lines = file($filename);

     foreach ($lines as $lineNumber => $lineContent) {
         if (isset($substitutions[$lineNumber])) {
             $lines[$lineNumber] = $substitutions[$lineNumber];
         }
     } 

     file_put_contents($filename, $lines);
 }
```

This, of course, doesn't handle all possible edge cases like, for example, when you don't have an access to the file or if you give non-existing line in substitutions array.

Comment: I have found the answer in another way. But I still value your hardwork. I'll first accept your answer and then min. Well, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is anybody found my question inappropriate/duplicate/not related to SO, then please just tell me to delete this question, don't down vote. Because I have only a little rep. If you down vote, I'll be unabled to ask questions anymore.

Comment: If you thing, my question is good and useful for others, then please upvote, So that it will be a good support